# How to add to an NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I was using a `NSMutableArray` and realized that using a dictionary is a lot simpler for what I am trying to achieve.

I want to save a key as a `NSString` and a value as an `int` in the dictionary. How is this done?  Secondly, what is the difference between mutable and a normal dictionary?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

A *mutable* dictionary can be changed, i.e. you can add and remove objects.
An *immutable* is fixed once it is created.

create and add:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:42] forKey:@"A cool number"];
```

and retrieve:

```
int myNumber = [[dict objectForKey:@"A cool number"] intValue];
```

Comment: Do you have to init with a capacity, or can it just be dynamic?

Comment: You don't have to specify the initial capacity, but you may see performance gains if you do. If you know upfront how many items it will contain, provide this number or a slightly bigger value.

Comment: asking for NSDictionary not NSMutableDictionary ?

Answer (score 39):

By setting you'd use `setValue:(id)value forKey:(id)key` method of `NSMutableDictionary` object:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:@"age"];
```

Or in modern Objective-C:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
dict[@"age"] = @5;
```

The difference between mutable and "normal" is, well, mutability. I.e. you can alter the contents of `NSMutableDictionary` (and `NSMutableArray`) while you can't do that with "normal" `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`

Comment: Shouldn't you wrap that integer in a NSNumber?

Comment: I have one more issue with this. I need to store a user entered text as string as well as the image reference(the index in the array of images) which the user is saving the text to. I tried a mutableArray of objects that have 2 variables, one for each I just mentioned. that wasnt working well when trying to populate the tableView with the array objects text values. SO I thought of a dictionary, the only problem is it doenst look like I could retrieve data by index, it has to be a key or value like a hashmap right?

Comment: @Johan - correct and updated!

@alJaree - yes, the dictionary is key-value store of sorts. I think in your position you'd be better of with array of dictionaries. Something like `[{image: "/path/to/img/1.jpg", data: "foo bar 1"}, {image: "/path/to/img/2.jpg", data: "foo bar 2"}, ..., {image: "/path/to/img/N.jpg", data: "foo bar N"}]`

Comment: This still wont work for me, because I need to retrieve text from each object and use that to fill the favorites UITableView as well as I need an index reference to the image array so that I can retrieve and display the selected favorite image. I tried the object that I described above, but the returned objects when reading from the array where NSStrings for some reason rather than the specific object that was stored. I am not sure what to do here,

Comment: I am thinking that I might need to just store NSStrings such as @"%d_%@, index, savedTitle and then just split the NSString and take and dipay what I need to. I am thinking in java terms, sure there must be a split function in obj c. :)

Answer (score 18):

When ever the array is declared, then only we have to add the key-value's in NSDictionary like

```
NSDictionary *normalDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Value1",@"Key1",@"Value2",@"Key2",@"Value3",@"Key3",nil];
```

we cannot add or remove the key values in this NSDictionary

Where as in NSMutableDictionary we can add the objects after intialization of array also
by using this method

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];'
[mutableDict setObject:@"Value1" forKey:@"Key1"];
[mutableDict setObject:@"Value2" forKey:@"Key2"];
[mutableDict setObject:@"Value3" forKey:@"Key3"];
```

for removing the key value we have to use the following code

```
[mutableDict removeObject:@"Value1" forKey:@"Key1"];
```

Answer (score 13):

#### Update version

**Objective-C**

Create:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"myKey1": @7, @"myKey2": @5};
```

Change:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];     //Make the dictionary mutable to change/add
mutableDictionary[@"myKey3"] = @3;
```

The short-hand syntax is called `Objective-C Literals`.

**Swift**

Create:

```
var dictionary = ["myKey1": 7, "myKey2": 5]
```

Change:

```
dictionary["myKey3"] = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to ask is "what is the difference between a mutable and a non-mutable array or dictionary."  Many times there different terms are used to describe things that you already know about.  In this case, you can replace the term "mutable" with "dynamic." So, a mutuable dictionary or array is one that is "dynamic" and can change at runtime, whereas a non-mutable dictionary or array is one that is "static" and defined in your code and does not change at runtime (in other words, you will not be adding, deleting or possibly sorting the elements.)

As to how it is done, you are asking us to repeat the documentation here.  All you need to do is to search in sample code and the Xcode documentation to see exactly how it is done.  But the mutable thing threw me too when I was first learning, so I'll give you that one!

Comment: Sometimes there isnt a decent enough explanation on the Xcode docs, it gets into deep theory without clear examples, not always, but sometimes. :P 
Yeah I understand the mutable (able to mutate) part now thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

For reference, you can also utilize `initWithDictionary` to init the `NSMutableDictionary` with a literal one:

```
NSMutableDictionary buttons = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: @{
    @"touch": @0,
    @"app": @0,
    @"back": @0,
    @"volup": @0,
    @"voldown": @0
}];
```