# How to add a string in a NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add to an NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159844/how-to-add-to-an-nsdictionary)

When I do that :

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionary];
[dic setValue:@"nvjd" forKey:@"name"];
```

my app just crash. I don't understand why. How should I add a string in a dictionary ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make your dictionary [mutable](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), otherwise it would not respond to the `setValue:forKey:` selector:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

This is a common pattern in cocoa: you often see classes declared in pairs: `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray`, `NSSet`/`NSMutableSet`, `NSString`/`NSMutableString`, and so on. Mutable version is capable of doing everything that the immutable version can do, but it also supports operations that change its content.

Answer (score 6):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic setValue:@"nvjd" forKey:@"name"];
```

or

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"nvjd",@"name" nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Either you initialize your `NSDictionary` with a key/value pair (or more than one), or create an `NSMutableDictionary` and add it later.

```
// Immutable
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"nvjd" forKey:@"name"];

// Mutable
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic setValue:@"nvjd" forKey:@"name"];
```